# How to setup audio from for lubuntu minimal install

Tags: ubuntu, audio, alsa, pulseaudio, lubuntu

Running a very stripped down lubuntu 14.04LTS x64 install.
I installed xorg and openbox and was up and running!

but I can't, for the life of me, seem to get any sound.
I installed alsamixer pulsaudio gstreamer alsa-utils and heap of related packages. tried to start, stop and restart things.

I have no idea what I'm doing any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to setup alsa or oss ?

Comment: alsa. although what ever works would be nice.

Comment: heres some alsa info:http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=e791a93b71f67edf11b583807eea359c5e71c9dd